# Controller Testing with Minitest and Devise failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, minitest

In a Rails 3.28 application using Devise, I setup a controller that checks whether a user is logged in or not with `if user_signed_in?`. Once the tests hit this line, I always get a `undefined method 'authenticate!' for nil:NilClass` error. I wanted to test some code in a scenario that no user is logged in.

I am thinking that I need to setup the tests according to the options specified in the Devise Wiki [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29), however, all the instructions pertain to rspec.

In particular, I think I need to have the following to work in minitest:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

Has anyone succeded in setting this up to have Devise work with minitest?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the following to your `minitest_helper.rb` file:

```
class MiniTest::Rails::ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! 

I have been struggling with my minitest helper over the past few weeks. This brings me closer to a defintive configuration file.

Comment: Blowmage, please, what's the latest version of this, since this was deprecated?  BTW, thanks for all the great work you do on minitest in Rails, it's really appreciated!

Comment: @Ivanoats, have a look at the devise readme at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: This solution also works inside class ActiveSupport::TestCase for those using test_helper.rb

Comment: DEPRECATION WARNING: [Devise] including `Devise::TestHelpers` is deprecated and will be removed from Devise.
For controller tests, please include `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` instead.